# Expo Development Build on Simulator Network connection lost

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, eas

I built development builds for an Expo an and as soon as I did that, I was not able to to connect to the expo development server from the iOs simulator. I tried:

- downgrading expo, react-native
- resetting router
- opening ports on the router
- running a completely new, 'naked' expo app and installing dev builds

Nothing works. Same with android and the emulator. And an iPhone.

On iOs I receive the error: `Failed to load app from http://...... The network connection was lost.`
On android I receive the error: `Unexpected end of stream on http://`

Does anyone have an idea what could be done to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by downgrading from NodeJS 20 to NodeJS 18 (the LTS). If you're on NodeJS version 20, you might wanna try to downgrade.

Comment: The same. If you are using Brew you could do:
brew install node@18 && brew unlink node && brew link --overwrite node@18

Comment: Setting up a new M2 Mac and this unfortunately did not work for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Solved this when nothing else worked!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using node 20.2.0

Updated to last stable version of node 20 (20.11.0) and worked. No need to downgrade to node 18.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: likely to be related to [this Node issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47822). Introduced in Node 20.0, fixed in 20.3.